# Cant make regex of google search?

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the content from a google search which fits the following format

```
<h3 class="zBAuLc"><div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">Google</div></h3>
```

How to make regular expression of this?

Here is what I've tried:

```
import requests, webbrowser
import re

userResearch = input('Enter what to search:')
print('Searching...')

searcher = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+userResearch)

results = re.findall(r'<h3 class=".+"><div class=".+">.+</div></h3>', searcher.text)


print (results)
```

But the re.findall does not return what I expect

Comment: Can you please specify what doesn't work for you and what you've already tried ?

Comment: @andymeissner results = re.findall(r'<h3 class=".+"><div class="[a-fA-F0-9]">.+</div></h3>', searcher.text) and it returns empty array

Answer (score 0):

You didn't escape the `/`.
Try the regex:

```
r'<h3 class=".+"><div class=".+">.+<\/div><\/h3>'
```

Comment: It returns a full page of google search but not the link. I need to find header and link (for example Apple; apple.com)

Comment: @CrownedPig, please edit your question accordingly and give a valid example.